# Web Component as Template Element

Tags: html, web-component

Is there a Web Component api to make my Custom Element behave like a Template tag?

```
<template></template>
```

Template tags are awesome and behave in a unique way, they are parsed but no rendered to the screen by default, an I ask myself is it possible to make my Custom Element behave the same way is there an api that would allow me to create my

```
<my-custom-template></my-custom-template>
```

tag?.

Comment: You mean https://developer.chrome.com/en/articles/declarative-shadow-dom/ ??